# Ajax Navigation Issue back button

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have an Ajax base Tab Switching Application in Java Spring Framework for which i have to handle Back button scenario. It was done successfully by below specifying code Now the effect am facing is first page load than tab switching jump appear for particular history selected Tab. If anybody help with Regards to this it would be great Thanks.

```
var innerTab = "";
function navigateAjaxHtmlSetup(target,response){
        if (typeof target == 'undefined') 
        target = "#ajax-container";  
        $(target).html(response);
        $("input[check-with-select]:checked").parent("label").parent("td").nextUntil(":last").find('select').attr('required', 'required');
        $(target).focus();
        $("#ajax-loader").hide();    
}
function pushStateToHistory(){
    var history = window.history;
    var location = window.location.pathname;
    history.pushState({}, "GHFP", location+activeTabs());
}

function anchorAjaxCall(self,url,state){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                var target = self.attr('targeto');
                navigateAjaxHtmlSetup(target,response);
                if (state)
                    pushStateToHistory();
//              if(innerTab != ""){
//                  var anchor  = $("a#"+innerTab);
//                  innerTab = "";
//                  anchorAjaxCall(anchor,anchor.attr('href'));
//              }
            }
        });
}

function activeTabs(){
    selectedTabList = $(".tabs-nav a.active");
    var activeURL;
    if (selectedTabList.length > 0){
        activeURL="#";
        selectedTabList.each(function(index,el){
            activeURL +="/"+$(el).attr('id');
        });
    }else{
        activeURL="";
    }   
    return activeURL;
}

function urlAjaxNavigationHandling(hash){
    if (hash.indexOf('/')!=-1)
    {
        var selectedTabList = hash.substring(1,hash.length).split('/');
        var anchor  = $("a#"+selectedTabList[1]);
        anchorAjaxCall(anchor,anchor.attr('href'),false);
        if (selectedTabList.length > 1)
            innerTab = selectedTabList[2];
    }  
}
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    urlAjaxNavigationHandling(window.location.hash);
};
```

Although my Question didn't relate to Spring or Java at all i just specify those as tag if anybody google around to implement Ajax base Application. This may help him as i didn't find any builtin support for JQuery in Spring Framework as Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 0):

Spring Framework is not like Rails, Grails comes close to Rails, but with Groovy.

The solution to your problem is basically working with the Browser's history, as you are already trying. The only think that I can add is you should look at the HTML5 History API http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html and also consider using a js framework like http://backbonejs.org/ which already has support for Routers.